# Qiskit: Error when importing libraries for ADMM optimizer

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, optimization

I would like to try and ADMM optimizer as shown in Qiskit Tutorial in Quantum Lab. Firstly, I imported necessary libraries (copy/paste from the Tutorial):

```
import time
from typing import List, Optional, Any
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

from docplex.mp.model import Model

from qiskit import BasicAer
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import QAOA, NumPyMinimumEigensolver
from qiskit.optimization.algorithms import CobylaOptimizer, MinimumEigenOptimizer
from qiskit.optimization.problems import QuadraticProgram
from qiskit.optimization.algorithms.admm_optimizer import ADMMParameters, ADMMOptimizer
```

When I started the import this error appeared:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-c32e151d13df> in <module>
     11 
     12 from qiskit import BasicAer
---> 13 from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import QAOA, NumPyMinimumEigensolver
     14 from qiskit.optimization.algorithms import CobylaOptimizer, MinimumEigenOptimizer
     15 from qiskit.optimization.problems import QuadraticProgram

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/__init__.py in <module>
     75 from .aqua_globals import aqua_globals
     76 from .quantum_instance import QuantumInstance
---> 77 from .algorithms import QuantumAlgorithm
     78 from ._logging import (QiskitLogDomains,
     79                        get_logging_level,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/__init__.py in <module>
    190 from .eigen_solvers import NumPyEigensolver, ExactEigensolver, EigensolverResult
    191 from .factorizers import Shor
--> 192 from .linear_solvers import HHL, NumPyLSsolver, ExactLSsolver
    193 from .minimum_eigen_solvers import (VQE, VQEResult, QAOA, IQPE, IQPEResult, QPE, QPEResult,
    194                                     ClassicalCPLEX, CPLEX_Ising, NumPyMinimumEigensolver,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/linear_solvers/__init__.py in <module>
     15 """ Linear Solvers Package """
     16 
---> 17 from .hhl import HHL
     18 from .numpy_ls_solver import NumPyLSsolver, ExactLSsolver
     19 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/linear_solvers/hhl.py in <module>
     24 from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance
     25 from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import QuantumAlgorithm
---> 26 from qiskit.ignis.verification.tomography import state_tomography_circuits, \
     27     StateTomographyFitter
     28 from qiskit.converters import circuit_to_dag

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/ignis/verification/__init__.py in <module>
     98 """
     99 from .quantum_volume import qv_circuits, QVFitter
--> 100 from .randomized_benchmarking import (CNOTDihedral,
    101                                       randomized_benchmarking_seq,
    102                                       RBFitter, InterleavedRBFitter,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/ignis/verification/randomized_benchmarking/__init__.py in <module>
     19 
     20 # Randomized Benchmarking functions
---> 21 from .circuits import randomized_benchmarking_seq
     22 from .dihedral import (CNOTDihedral, decompose_cnotdihedral, random_cnotdihedral)
     23 from .fitters import (RBFitter, InterleavedRBFitter, PurityRBFitter,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/ignis/verification/randomized_benchmarking/circuits.py in <module>
    204                                 is_purity: bool = False,
    205                                 group_gates: Optional[str] = None,
--> 206                                 rand_seed: Optional[Union[int, RandomState]] = None) -> \
    207         (List[List[qiskit.QuantumCircuit]], List[List[int]],
    208          Optional[List[List[qiskit.QuantumCircuit]]],

AttributeError: module 'qiskit' has no attribute 'quantum_info'
```

Since I only copied the code, it seems there is some bug. **Does anybody know how to solve this?**

*Note: I work in Quantum Lab in IBM Q Experience interface*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a glitch. It is not reproducible under my account. I've seen similar errors when there's mismatch in versions between Qiskit Aqua and Terra installed locally, but I don't think it is the case in Quantum Lab.
Try to restart the kernel or create a new notebook and run the same imports.

Comment: I tried to run the code again and it works. Probably there was some error on Quantum Lab side. Thanks for the suggestion.